# Redirect Permanent and https

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I just set up https on my server, and I have an issue with redirect permanent.

If I have a link for example http://domain.com/index.html it redirect me on

```
https://www.domain.comindex.html
```

The / is missing and I can't figure out how to fix it.

It's work with http://www.domain.com/index.html

Here is my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
  ServerName www.domain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile ssl.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Get rid of the second one.

Your original problem was a typo in the target; the source and target of a redirect **must** have matching slashes.

Browser cache persistence explains the rest.

Also note that in apache 2.2, `NameVirtualHost *:80` is *not* optional, if you have more than one vhost.

In apache 2.4, it guesses what you mean and does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you duplicating your virtual hosts definitions? You can just use a line like:

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
```

Here is the [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). So, one of the VH should be enough instead of two (of port 80). You can keep the working one :)